# Solving an exercise in Pinter's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is an exercise 5ch,D7 in Pinter's *Abstract Algebra*.

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and let $K = \{a \in G : axa^{-1} \in H$
>   for every $x \in H\}$. Prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I have problems proving that $K$ is *closed under inverses*, in other words that $a \in K \implies a^{-1} \in K$. If we dealt with finite groups, I could use this argument: let $a \in K$ and let's take arbitrary $x \in H$, then there is some $y \in H$ such that $aya^{-1} = x$. We know that $y = (a^{-1}a)y(a^{-1}a) $ $= a^{-1}(aya^{-1})a = a^{-1}xa \in H$, hence $a^{-1} \in K$.

At this stage in the book, if the group is infinite, I can't assume that given two elements of a group $a$ and $b$, there is some element $x$ such that $a = bx$ (I even don't know whether it is true). Is it possible to solve this exercise without using this assumption? Can you provide a hint?

Comment: The set you describe is called the normalizer of $H$ in $G$. Check out https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Normalizer_is_Subgroup

Comment: This is not the same as the definition of the normalizer. The definition of the normalizer uses $aHa^{-1}=H$ whereas we only have $aHa^{-1}\subseteq H$. These are equivalent if $H$ is finite, but we are not assuming that.

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b\in G$, then $x=b^{-1}a\in G$ solves $a=bx$. So your proof works fine, except you have some of your $a$'s and $x$'s swapped, and the last '$H$' should be a $K$.

Edit: 
What you are trying to prove is false.

Let $G$ be a free group on $s,r,t$. Let $H$ be the subgroup of words that when reduced start with $s$ and end with $s^{-1}$ (and also the identity element). The element $x=srs^{-1}$ is in $H$ and not in $sHs^{-1}$. So $s\in K$ (by definition of $H$) but $s^{-1}\notin K$ (because $s^{-1}xs\notin H$).

Comment: I still don't see how to show that for any $x \in H$, there is $y \in H$ such that $aya^{-1} = x$ (given that $aka^{-1} \in H$ for any $k \in H$).

Comment: Given $x\in H$ and $a\in K$, by definition of $K$, we have $y=axa^{-1}\in H$. But then we have $a^{-1}ya=x\in H$ by our initial data.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't quite what I was aiming for. I'll get back to you.